# How do I add a task to main 'build' task in gradle

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

When I try to add a task to the main build task with the following code:

```
rootProject.tasks.getByName('build').dependsOn mytask
```

It complains when I run `gradle(w) build` with the output:

```
* Where:
Build file '...' line
: ...

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':myapp'.
> Task with name 'build' not found in root project 'main'.
```

how do i add the task to the build task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your build has no `build` task, at least at the time when above line gets evaluated. Usually, the `build` task gets added by the `java-base` plugin, which in turns gets applied by plugins such as `java`, `groovy`, or `scala`. So make sure to apply one of these plugins first. Or, if you don't use any of them, declare your own `build` task.

Comment: will defining my own build task override the base plugin?

Comment: There can't be two tasks with the same name in the same project. Declaring the second task will result in an error. If your code requires the `java-base` plugin, just apply it. (Gradle makes sure that each plugin is only run once.) If you want to do some conditional configuration if and when the `java-base` plugin is added by somebody else, you can use `plugins.withType(JavaBasePlugin) { ... }`.