# No Gradle "build" task despite build.gradle applying plugin com.android.application

Tags: android, gradle

Somehow I don't have a `build` task:

```
$ ./gradlew tasks --all
:tasks

------------------------------------------------------------
All tasks runnable from root project
------------------------------------------------------------

Build Setup tasks
-----------------
init - Initializes a new Gradle build. [incubating] [wrapper]
wrapper - Generates Gradle wrapper files. [incubating]

Help tasks
----------
components - Displays the components produced by root project 'apps-android-commons'. [incubating]
dependencies - Displays all dependencies declared in root project 'apps-android-commons'.
dependencyInsight - Displays the insight into a specific dependency in root project 'apps-android-commons'.
help - Displays a help message.
model - Displays the configuration model of root project 'apps-android-commons'. [incubating]
projects - Displays the sub-projects of root project 'apps-android-commons'.
properties - Displays the properties of root project 'apps-android-commons'.
tasks - Displays the tasks runnable from root project 'apps-android-commons'.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Despite my `commons/app/build.gradle` that applies (as described [in this other QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21396777/how-do-i-add-a-task-to-main-build-task-in-gradle)) a relevant plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1.1@aar'
    compile 'in.yuvi:http.fluent:1.3'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.8.4'
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.5.0'
    compile 'org.mediawiki:api:1.3'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'

    //noinspection GradleDependency - old version has required feature
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:1.4'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "fr.free.nrw.commons"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23

        ndk {
            moduleName "libtranscode"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
        disable 'ExtraTranslation'
    }
}
```

**QUESTION:** Why is that, am I doing something wrong?

Here is my project structure:

```
ROOT
 /commons
   /app
```

... and I execute `./gradlew` in ROOT.

Comment: Have you executed the command in an appropriate folder?

Comment: What does the other Gradle file look like? In any case, why aren't you using the new project wizard of Android Studio?

Comment: @Opal: Added folder information, thanks!

Comment: @Opal: That was the problem it seems, added answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

If your folder is:

```
ROOT
 /commons
   /app
```

... then execute `.gradlew` in the `commons` folder, not in `ROOT`.

*Thanks @Opal for the tip!*